# Liferay portlet creation in edit mode

Tags: configuration, portlet, liferay, edit

I am trying to create a liferay portlet that supports edit as well as view mode.
I am using the default MVCPortlet provided in liferay source.

I have configured the portlet.xml as follows

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>inline-portlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>inline</display-name>
    <portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>edit-jsp</name>
        <value>/edit.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-jsp</name>
        <value>/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
    </supports>
    <portlet-info>
        <title>inline</title>
        <short-title>inline</short-title>
        <keywords>inline</keywords>
    </portlet-info>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>guest</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

When I deploy it I am unable to see any new tab created in the edit mode that is when we click on the wrench like icon.

Is there any configuration I am missing. I already have edit.jsp and view.jsp in root directory. The view is consistent but cannot find the edit.jsp in other words it is not called.

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the portlet Edit mode in Liferay is called "Preference"

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the Edit mode in the `portlet.xml` ? like this ?

```xml
<supports>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
    <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
    <portlet-mode>help</portlet-mode>
</supports>
```

All modes used by the portlet must be explicit set in this part of the config of `portlet.xml` and you have to do this to all portlets you want more than view mode.

Also you could write a mode handler like this in your class, just implement `PortletListener`

it could be useful for debugging at least.

```java
public void handleResourceRequest(ResourceRequest request,
            ResourceResponse response,
            Window window) {
// Switch the view according to the portlet mode
if (request.getPortletMode() == PortletMode.EDIT){
    this.addWindow(editWindow);
}else if (request.getPortletMode() == PortletMode.VIEW){
    window.setContent(viewContent);
}else if (request.getPortletMode() == PortletMode.HELP)
    window.setContent(helpContent);
}
```

Also check the portlet permissions, did you try as an admin ? they should see it no matter what. regular users on the other hand should have permissions to set preferences of a specific portlet.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you create custom portlets with an edit mode, this mode will not appear under a tab underneath the Configuration icon like Liferay's default portlets. Instead, your edit mode's JSP will be accessible via a new icon, which is called Preferences.

The portlet spec only defines VIEW, EDIT and HELP modes, but allows custom portlet modes to be added to the list. This is exactly what Liferay did for its default portlets. They use the CONFIG custom portlet mode. For an example of how to implement this, check [this thread's last post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/283177).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create class that implements

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.ConfigurationAction
```

and you must register it in `liferay-portlet.xml` in the portlet node.

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>MyPortlet</portlet-name>
    <configuration-action-class>com.mydomain.MyConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
</portlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your case, besides `portlet.xml` config, you need to implement the `doView`, `doEdit` and `processAction` methods in your class that can extend `MVCPortlet`. "Liferay in Action" book has a good example.

Or you can do all the logic within jsp files and taglibs of Liferay. Edit mode is available clicking in Preferences.